# Is there a way of ensuring the template argument passed in C++ is an iterator?

Tags: c++, templates

In C++, I am making an implementation of the `vector` class and came across an error when using any type as the argument for `T`:

```
void insert(iterator where, size_type count, const_reference value = T()){...}

template <typename InIt>
void insert(iterator where, InIt first, InIt last){...}
```

When doing the following:

```
vector<int> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    v.push_back(i + 1);
}
v.insert(v.begin() + 2, 10, 8);
v.insert(v.begin() + 4, 9);
```

It takes the argument for `InIt` as `int`, when it should in fact be an `iterator` type class and means that the wrong function is called, resulting in internal memory errors. As a result, I have had to remove the `insert` function with the `template <typename InIt>` argument as it ruins my implementation. I have tried this with `std::string` and the same problem occurs.

Is there anything I can do to differentiate these two functions?

Comment: What you're really looking for is Concepts Lite, which are still in design phase. Maybe we'll see them in the next standard (C++17) or around that time in a TS. Meanwhile, you can probably do what you want using SFINAE/std::enable_if

Comment: Bad design, Besides some special iterators (output_iterator) an iterator has no notion of the container. Hence `void insert(iterator where, InIt first, InIt last){...}` is bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what SFINAE is for - remove the 2nd overload from the overload set if `InIt` is not something that looks like an iterator. In this case, you just want an input iterator, which has to be both incrementable and dereferencable:

```
template <typename InIt,
          typename = decltype(*std::declval<InIt&>(),
                              ++std::declval<InIt&>())>
void insert(iterator where, InIt first, InIt last)
{
    ...
}
```

If you were to call `insert` with some integral type (so that it can be converted to `size_t`), `*std::declval<InIt&>` would be an invalid expression since integral types aren't dereferencable - so template deduction would fail. Because **S**ubstitution **F**ailure **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror, the effect is that this overload is removed from consideration, and the first one would be called instead.

Comment: @Barry - thanks for the answer :) Do you think there are any suitable variations of this code for earlier than C++11 or is `std::enable_if` the best way to go?

Comment: @Joe pre-C++11 I'd probably go for a return type of `typename boost::disable_if<typename boost::is_integral<InIt>::type>::type` for simplicity.

Comment: I'm sorry, is it enough to assume that the type of the 2nd argument is not integral to claim it's an iterator? what if an empty class or a float is passed instead?

Answer (score 2):

From the [**Concepts *Iterator***](https://web.archive.org/web/20180527012215/http://en.cppreference.com:80/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) reference you have several options, to check for particular types of *iterators*:

> [image: C++ Concepts] ([see](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611055249/http://en.cppreference.com:80/w/cpp/concept))

Comment: In the absence of Concepts into the language, this answer is insufficient to solve the question

Comment: @KABoissonneault Most of the iterator concepts are already supported with the current standard.

Comment: My point is that while Concepts are existent in the standard library, they are absent from the core language, and therefore are hard for the average user to apply properly.
You can always use the void_t trick with some typedef/aliases but it's not exactly a clean solution, especially if your code is exposed to other users